# Как задвинуть элемент за поля документа?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Речь идет о красном кружке справа, на первый взгляд кажется что проблемы нет, но если выбрать мобильное устройство в DevTools, то кружок отказывается заезжать за границы, пробовал менять единицы измерения сдвига, результат не меняется[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #1D1D1D;
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.elipse-1 {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #FF8E8E 0%, #F62424 100%);
    top: 287px;
    left: 99.25%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="elipse-1"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не проще ли использовать фиксированый отступ `right` в пикселях вместо `left` в процентах?

Comment: @Neverm1ndo не совсем понимаю как это, можно подробнее?

Comment: @Neverm1ndo кажется понял, но это все равно не решает проблему

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пожалуйста!

```
body {
    height: 3000px
}

.elipse-1 {
    position: absolute;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    top: 287px;
    right: 0;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px
}

.elipse-1::after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #ff8e8e 0%, #f62424 100%);
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(50%);
    border-radius: 50%
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! 
Почему ваш способ с transform работает, а обычный сдвиг элемента вызывает данную проблему?